# PC Connected to A/V Receiver via HDMI - Issues When Switching Sources on Receiver

Tags: graphics-card, display

I just recently bought a 50ft. HDMI cable with Redmere from Monoprice so that I can finally hook my gaming PC (in another room) up to my 60" plasma.  Once I figured out how to deal with some underscan issues (corrected in the Catalyst Control Panel), I stumbled upon another issue.

The PC is connected to an Onkyo TX-SR608 A/V receiver via HDMI and then the receiver connects to the TV via another HDMI cable.  I use the A/V receiver to switch between various sources (PS3, 360, Wii, Dune media player, and now PC).  When I switch away from the PC input to another device and then switch back, I get "No Signal" on the TV.  Power cycling the receiver and the TV do not correct this issue.  The only way I've found to correct the issue is to make some change to resolution or monitor settings on the PC, say, switch output to my desktop monitor and then back to the TV.  None of the other devices have this issue... they're all happy to be switched to and from without a care in the world.

Can anyone suggest why this is occurring?  I'm not sure if it would be an HDCP issue, for instance, and how to correct it if so.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: My guess is that your cable is of poor quality (too cheap). Before you go out and buy another (more expensive) cable, I'd recommend using one of your console's cable to hook your PC and your PC's to hook one of your consoles then test it out.

Comment: @Nolonar I doubt that.  Monoprice's cables are inexpensive but definitely not of poor quality.  The rest of my HDMI cables are from Monoprice as well.  Further, none of them are nearly long enough, and I'm not too excited about the prospect of dragging my PC out to my living room and trying to get it hooked up.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with different driver versions for your video card?

Comment: @happy_soil I just installed the latest version from AMD's website (I have a Radeon 7850). No change I'm afraid.

Comment: @NaOH From a quick Google search, I saw people having success using older versions. It's probably worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is resolved now. Not sure exactly what did it, but here's what I did when I got home today:

1. Tested PC connected directly to TV, bypassing the AVR. Switching inputs on the TV did not cause the handshake issue.
2. Connected PC to "PC" input (was previously on whatever else was free). My Wii was on the PC input previously for some reason.
3. Set Monitor output to Bypass, and set input to Game Mode and Bypass under picture control.

Now everything's working quite swell. Switching inputs with the AVR now no longer has any issues.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Comment: I am havng the same issue, and I have also a Onky receiver. Could you please explaing what you mean with step 3? "Set monitor output to Bypass"?

Comment: @Martijn - In the end I actually bypassed the receiver for video.  I plugged my PC directly into another input on my TV, and ran audio to the receiver via optical.